# How to combine/merge multiple graphs using LEMON (or BGL)

Tags: c++, graph, boost-graph, lemon-graph-library

I am looking for a way to merge multiple Graphs into a single Graph using [LEMON](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon). If it can not be done, I'd also be interested in solutions using [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html).

The background is, that I want to define smaller structural units as graphs, annotate them with properties and add multiple copies of them together to create more complex structures.

In the example below, I have 3 graphs `g1`,`g2`. and `g3` consisting of a single vertex. I want to combine them into a single graph and be able to add edges to connect the vertices inside the resulting graph. However, I don't know how to specify the `copyGraph` function correctly so that all vertices of `g1`, `g2`, and `g3` end up in the same graph at the end. Also, if `g1` etc. contained multiple connected vertices, these edges should remain intact.

The example also contains a fourth graph `gTest` which looks like the result I want to achieve. However, `gTest` here is created from scratch and not by combining the previously exisiting graphs. This is for demonstration/clarification and produces the following graphic:
[image: Output of the program]

To compile the code using g++, use

`g++ -lemon main.cpp`

```
#include <lemon/list_graph.h>
#include <lemon/graph_to_eps.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace lemon;
    typedef dim2::Point<int> Point;

    ListGraph g1; 
    ListGraph::NodeMap<Point> coords1(g1);
    ListGraph::Node n1 = g1.addNode();
    coords1[n1] = Point(10,20);

    ListGraph g2; 
    ListGraph::NodeMap<Point> coords2(g2);
    ListGraph::Node n2 = g2.addNode();
    coords2[n2] = Point(20,20);

    ListGraph g3; 
    ListGraph::NodeMap<Point> coords3(g3);
    ListGraph::Node n3 = g3.addNode();
    coords3[n3] = Point(15,25);


    // pseudo-code of the copy-operation:
    // copyGraph(g1, g3);
    // copyGraph(g2, g3);
    //  
    // g3.addEdge(n1,n3)
    // g3.addEdge(n2,n3)



    // Result should look similar to what the following produces
    ListGraph gTest;
    ListGraph::NodeMap<Point> coordsTest(gTest);
    ListGraph::Node n1Test = gTest.addNode();
    coordsTest[n1Test] = Point(10,20);
    ListGraph::Node n2Test = gTest.addNode();
    coordsTest[n2Test] = Point(20,20);
    ListGraph::Node n3Test = gTest.addNode();
    coordsTest[n3Test] = Point(15,25);

    ListGraph::Edge e1Test = gTest.addEdge(n3Test, n1Test);
    ListGraph::Edge e2Test = gTest.addEdge(n3Test, n2Test);

    graphToEps(gTest, "gTest.eps")
        .coords(coordsTest)
        .nodeTexts(coordsTest)
        .run();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific question is. It looks like you have accomplished your goal here.

Comment: The shown result is only a demonstration of the result I want to achieve. For the demonstration I created the result from scratch. What I am looking for is a way to create the result by combining `g1`, `g2` and `g3`. (The part that only exists as pseudo-code). I'm fairly certain it can be done using some form of copy-operation but I can't figure out how to do it correctly